# Numba : difference between first time execution and following executions

Tags: python, numba, execution-time

I just started to use numba to improve performance of my programs. I have reduce the case that I will present

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from time import time


def dt_max(U,f, eps=1e-5):
    return np.min( np.abs( U ) / ( np.abs( f ) + eps ) )

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def fast_dt_max(U,f, eps=1e-5):      
    m=U[0]
    if m<0 : m=-U[0]
    for i in range(len(U)) :
        v = abs(U[i]) / ( abs(f[i]) + eps )
        if v < m : m = v
    return m


N=100
Niter = int(1e5)

x=np.linspace(-50,50,N)

t0 = time()
for i in range(Niter):
    dt_max(x,x)
print('numpy',time()-t0)

t0 = time()
for i in range(Niter):
    fast_dt_max(x,x)
print('numba' ,time()-t0)
```

I execute this entire file in spyder under the following distribution :

```
Python 3.5.5 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Apr  7 2018, 04:52:34) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

The problem is the following. When I execute for the first time this program, it looks work good :

```
runfile('E:/02-Codes/TestCode/Python_numba/bug_second_execution.py', wdir='E:/02-Codes/TestCode/Python_numba')
numpy 0.45239996910095215
numba 0.2964000701904297
```

But when I repeat the execution of all file :

```
runfile('E:/02-Codes/TestCode/Python_numba/bug_second_execution.py', wdir='E:/02-Codes/TestCode/Python_numba')
numpy 0.45239996910095215
numba 3.5879998207092285

runfile('E:/02-Codes/TestCode/Python_numba/bug_second_execution.py', wdir='E:/02-Codes/TestCode/Python_numba')
numpy 0.4679999351501465
numba 3.5734000205993652
```

The numba's performance are not the same at all. If I restart Python  kernel in my spyder environment, the problemn happens again : first execution is good, all the followings not.

So the first question is : why ? and the second is : how to avoid that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: The problem seems to come from setting a default variable for eps. This causes a recompilation after reopening the interpreter. You can check this behaviour with setting the environment variable  NUMBA_DEBUG_CACHE to one. eg. (set NUMBA_DEBUG_CACHE=1) and setting no default value for eps. If there are many cached versions for one function in the cache directory, this can also explain the very slow timing for loading the precached version.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot Max for the answer.

Indeed, the default value for eps is the reason of the problem. If I switch in debug mode (thanks Max for this tips!) :

```
import os
os.environ['NUMBA_DEBUG_CACHE'] = '1'
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
from time import time

@nb.njit(cache=True)
def fast_dt_max(U,f, eps=1e-5):
    m=U[0]
    if m<0 : m=-U[0]
    for i in range(len(U)) :
        v = abs(U[i]) / ( abs(f[i]) + eps )
        if v < m : m = v
    return m
```

This code shows that at each execution, 4 operations is done (2 loads, and 2 saving). Now if I remove the default value for eps, by keeping debug mode :

```
@nb.njit(cache=True)
def fast_dt_max(U,f, eps):
    m=U[0]
    if m<0 : m=-U[0]
    for i in range(len(U)) :
        v = abs(U[i]) / ( abs(f[i]) + eps )
        if v < m : m = v
    return m
```

the successive call to the function, let appear only 2 operations per execution (1 load + 1 saving)

CONCLUSION : Not use default parameter values in numba function.

Thanks !

Comment: BTW: Your Numba and Numpy version are not equal. If a division by zero occurs the Numba version will act by default like Python and raise an exception. In Numpy a division by zero results in inf and you will see a Runtime Warning. If you write @nb.njit(cache=True,error_model="numpy") Numba will behave like Numpy, but without a runtime warning.

Comment: What do you mean by "Numba and Numpy version are not equal" ? My numba version is 0.40.1 and my numpy version is 1.14.5.

Comment: Good tips for error_model="numpy", it let to treat without error case with eps=0. Thanks !

Comment: I meant that in case of a division by zero your Numba version raises an exception without setting error_model="numpy", while the numpy function doesn't. That can lead to unwanted behaviour.

Comment: ok, not equal in the meaning that not works identically. I understand, thanks.